# Check string starting with substring using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to check if `randomString` starting with `just.` (including the dot).

This should give me false but it's not the case:

```js
var randomString = 'justanother.string';
 
var a = randomString.match('^just\.');
 
console.log(a);
```

I probably missed something in the regex argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use create a [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and the use [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method.

```js
var randomString = 'justanother.string';
var a = /^just\./.test(randomString)
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple, you didn't create regex propertly.
`'this is not regex'`
`/this is regex/`
`new RexExp('this is also regex')`

```js
var randomString = 'justanother.string';
 
var a = randomString.match(/^just\./);

console.log(a);

// I sugest dooing something like this
const startsWithJust = (string) => /^just\./.test(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var randomString = 'justanother.string';
var another = 'just.....................';
console.log(  randomString.match('^(just[.]).*') );
console.log(  another.match('^just[.].*') );
```

Comment: noo this would match `just.` but also `just` and `just.......................................................`

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to keep your lines the same only one change is needed.

```
var a = randomString.match('^just\\.');
```

you need to escape the first backslash.